Is this homebrew magic item balanced for level 3, and is it worded in the same way a published magic item would be?
It's called the infinite quiver. My DM gave it to me, since I think everyone is getting a custom magic item. The description reads,

Within this magical quiver reside an unlimited amount of arrows, which can only be used by those who wear this sacred artifact. Due to the unique, magical nature of this artifact, arrows pulled from within cannot be sold or traded, and this artifact can only be destroyed by a disintegrate spell, or an effect of similar nature. Arrows from this artifact disappear shortly after hitting a surface or the designated target, and deal one additional damage. This damage is non-magical unless another effect states otherwise.(Edit)

If it makes any difference, I'm playing a fairy, and therefore will be using a shortbow instead of a longbow.

You might want to ask your DM to clarify whether arrows from the quiver are magical.  Some creatures have resistance or are immune to damage from regular arrows, but not magical ones.  I'm guessing the arrows are magical, but it'd be good for you to know.  Also, why can't a fairy use a longbow?  Like maybe a fairy-sized longbow?  Did the DM say you can't use a longbow?

@Jack The fairy can't use a longbow because it's heavy, and the fairy is small, so they have disadvantage with heavy weapons. I'll ask the DM if the arrows are magical, but I'm not entirely sure, as I wasn't thinking about that when I made the item.

@Jack The arrows are non-magic.

To be explicit, the arrows do have +1 damage, but do not have +1 attack?

@JoelHarmon Correct. The +1 damage is only due to the arrows disappearing, thus doing more damage because of the bleeding, because the arrow doesn't stop them from bleeding anymore because it's gone.

In the title, I'd replace "real" with "published" or "in the source books". Your creation is as real as it gets at your table.

This item seems balanced for a level 3 PC
In short, this item allows you to have infinite ammo and deal +1 damage. There are other game features that allow very similar effects, which are attainable at low level.
The best example I can think of is the Artificer infusion, Repeating Shot (TCoE, p.22):

Repeating Shot
Prerequisite: A simple or martial weapon with the ammunition property (requires attunement)
This magic weapon grants a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it when it's used to make a ranged attack, and it ignores the loading property if it has it.
If the weapon lacks ammunition, it produces its own, automatically creating one piece of magic ammunition when the wielder makes a ranged attack with it. The ammunition created by the weapon vanishes the instant after it hits or misses a target.

An Artificer could have this as early as level 2, and does basically the same thing (albeit it also gives +1 to the attack roll as well, and does magical damage, whereas the item in your question appears to only give +1 to the damage and does not deal magical damage).
It does require attunement, so this implies that your quiver perhaps also ought to require attunement, but if your DM makes that change, I'd also recommend they give you the +1 to attack rolls with those arrows as well.
That said, since the arrows from your quiver are not considered magical, whereas the above quoted game feature does provide magical damage, that "weakens" this item enough that it probably doesn't need attunement after all (attunement is usually a way to counterbalance a powerful item that is on the upper limit of a certain rarity-bracket's power level).

As for the wording of the magic item, it doesn't look like an official description. I would expect its wording to read more like how the above quote of mine is worded. It should mention the +1 bit first, and mention the "infinite" aspect of it next.
Regarding how to destroy the magic item (disintegrate spell), I would imagine that would be added at the end, perhaps under its own sub-section, similar to how magic items of artifact rarity are worded. Taking the Orb of Dragonkind as an example:

Destroying an Orb. An Orb of Dragonkind appears fragile but is impervious to most damage, including the attacks and breath weapons of dragons. A disintegrate spell or one good hit from a +3 magic weapon is sufficient to destroy an orb, however.

This appears at the very end of the item's description, so that part of your item's description probably ought to go at the end as well (although on second thoughts, giving it a sub-section like the above quote might be a bit overkill for a non-artifact item).

A less good example of a feature that does something similar to the quiver is the "Moon Bow" Eldritch Invocation from an old Unearthed Arcana, "Warlock and Wizard", which a warlock could pick up at 3rd level when they pick Pact of the Blade. It says: "When you draw back its string and fire, it creates an arrow of white wood, which vanishes after 1 minute." It also does other stuff, like allowing you to "smite" similar to the published Eldritch Smite invocation, and doesn't appear to offer +1 to attack or damage, so overall it's not as good-a-comparison vs. the Repeating Shot infusion.

Another good reference point for "standard" wording is the Swift Quiver spell. The Bracer of Flying Daggers might also be a useful reference.

This seems balanced, but the actual rules text need some work.
The first thing I noticed was this: "this artifact can only be destroyed by a disintegrate spell, or an effect of similar nature". In D&D, at least in the context of magic items, "artifact" is a special term that refers to "a unique magic item of tremendous power" (DMG p.219), which doesn't appear to apply here. Normally it's not necessary to describe what can and can't destroy a magic item, but artifacts in specific are immune to being destroyed except by one or two unusual methods, such as being crushed under a god's heel or struck by a +3 weapon. The quiver is clearly not an artifact, but the 'can only be destroyed by disintegrate' seems like it's leaning that direction, which is odd.
Normal magic items generally "have resistance to all damage" (DMG p.141) with a few rare exceptions like the Unbreakable Arrow (XGtE p.139). Most effects don't deal damage to worn items anyway -- I've never seen even mundane gear get destroyed, much less a magic item, so I have a hard time imagining how this would ever come up in play -- but it's probably harmless.*
Next, it states the arrows can only be used by somebody who wears the quiver and the arrows can't be traded or sold. How does that manifest? Are you enchanted so that you physically can't force yourself to hand the arrows to other people, or what? The item description should tell us what the characters experience rather than just stating that they can't do a thing.
I would probably rewrite this to say something like "Arrows drawn from this quiver disappear in a puff of sparkling dust a few moments after they leave the wielder's hand, just enough time to hit or miss a target. They don't last long enough for another creature to borrow an arrow for their own use."  It's implicit that you can't sell the arrows if they disintegrate after a couple seconds, no need to state it. (Pick your own visual effect -- flash of light, disintegrate into nothingness, sparkles, just vanish with no fanfare, whatever fits your idiom. Since you said you're a fairy, I went with fairy-dust.)
*The thing that could be an exploit of indestructibility is using the quiver as a structural support -- like can I stop a slow-crushing-walls trap by putting my quiver between the walls, stopping them dead as they're unable to crush the quiver?

Fairly balanced, or even a little underpowered
Breakdown of properties
Infinite arrows for the user
Personally I've never been in a table that tracks arrows/ammunition (unless magic). Mayyybe this could be something done at early levels (1-2) or as part of an extended campaign in wilderness but overall it's more of a ribbon ability / explanation of why you don't have to care about them.
An argument could be made that this item is more powerful than the Efficient Quiver, but frankly the quiver is quite underwhelming.
Wording around the arrows disappearing etc could be refined a bit, I'm assuming it's just to prevent shenanigans around producing/selling infinite arrows.
Hard to destroy
Carried/worn equipment is typically unaffected by most things (e.g. the Fireball spell: ignites flammable objects in the area that aren’t being worn or carried). Still, a nice ribbon and gives a bit more mystique; but if the enemies (/DM) are going for your magic items they'll probably have Disintegrate.
Magic arrows (+1 damage)
This is the main feature!
One could compare it to Ammunition+1 which is an uncommon consumable item; but you have unlimited number of those! On the other hand, you only get +1 to damage, not to hit and the damage isn't magical (based on the updated answer).
I think a better comparison is a Weapon+1, which is also uncommon but provides a permanent boost. The only difference is that your bonus is coming from the arrows but that doesn't impact the actual mechanical benefit*:

magic damage: ⛔
bonus to hit: ⛔
bonus to damage: ✅

*There is one case it matters. If you later get a Weapon+1, the bonuses will stack. Perhaps this could be considered a Weapon+2 which is rare; but note that the main reason for that is the bonus to hit, not the damage. Since your arrows do not provide that, I'd say that it's not that impactful. Additionally, this would prevent you from using specialised ammunition, eg +1/2/3 or special ones.
Regarding attunement, it feels that flavor-wise it might be suitable, but given the power level it'd be a waste of an attunement slot.
tl;dr: it's a Weapon "+0.5" with the potential of transforming a Weapon+1 to a Weapon "+1.5" (or even +1.25 given the limitations)

The arrows don't do magic DMG, the +1 DMG is because of the disappearing, the arrow doesn't stop the target from bleeding since it's gone

@Tasi interesting, that could be something worth mentioning in the wording; as it's a magical quiver, I'd assume the arrows will also deal magic damage. It's also worth specifying the damage type of the +1; if it's related to bleeding it could be necrotic but the same type as the arrow also works. Either way, if it's not making the damage magical then it's a bit less powerful. Definitely a nice boost at level 3 though!

Ok, I updated the description of the item to specify that the damage is non-magical, UNLESS another effect states otherwise.
